# Verb not at the last position in a subordinate sentence

Tags: grammar-identification

*Okay", hat der Igel gesagt, "wetten wir, dass ich schneller laufe als Sie!*

Why is "laufe" preceding "als Sie!" here?
Is it grammatically correct to reverse their positions

Comment: Duplicate of [Conjugated verb NOT in the last position in a subordinate clause](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39365/conjugated-verb-not-in-the-last-position-in-a-subordinate-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wetten wir, dass ich schneller laufe als Sie!
>
> Wetten wir, dass ich schneller laufe als ein Hase!

This is correct and all a matter of emphasis. As you maybe already know, the first thing in a German sentence is what gets the most emphasis, followed by the last thing.

> Wetten wir, dass ich schneller als Sie laufe!
>
> Wetten wir, dass ich besser als Sie schummle!

Comment: So, it is still correct to reverse their positions right? (so "laufe" ends up being last) On a slightly unrelated note, what part of speech is "als Sie" considered to be? Is it an adverb?

Comment: It's a comparison, introducing a Prädikativ ("nominative object"). And yes, it can also be put at the usual position. Such comparisons belong to the few things which may be placed outside of the *Verbklammer*.

Comment: could you please give me more info regarding what exactly *Verbklammer* is?

Comment: German sentence construction follows the idea of *embracing* things belonging together by parts which are clearly marked as related. Such as an article or pronoun and the corresponding noun or two parts of a verb. The *Verbklammer* is the outermost brace in a clause, and may even be the outermost brace in a whole sentence (embracing subordinate *Verbklammern*). Unlike commas, these braces are available in speech, too.

Answer (score 3):

Putting things after the *Verbklammer* is only common for particular elements. Comparisons with 'als' are one of those elements.

> Wetten, dass ich schneller laufe als Sie!
>
> *Wetten, dass ich schneller laufe zum Zoo!

The first example is unremarkable, the second would be unusual, used primarily in poetry to make things scan right.