# Verb vor der Präposition in Nebensatz

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

Ich habe eine Frage zu einem Satz, den ich in einem Buch (*Das Parfum*) gefunden habe. Der ganze Satz lautet

> Es war also später Nachmittag, will sagen ein Zustand und Zeitpunkt in Grenouilles Seele, wie er im Süden am Ende der Siesta herrscht, wenn die mittägliche Lähmung langsam abfällt von der Landschaft und das zurückgehaltene Leben wieder beginnen will.

Meine Frage ist besonders zu der Phrase

> …, wenn die mittägliche Lähmung langsam abfällt von der Landschaft …

Ich habe gelernt, dass bei Nebensätze das Verb immer am Ende des Satzes ist. Wieso ist dann "abfällt" vor der Präposition und nicht danach? Sollte es nicht heißen:

> …, wenn die mittägliche Lähmung von der Landschaft abfällt …

Oder gibt es eine andere Regel dafür?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Verwandt (auf Englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39365, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44302

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In den meisten Nebensätzen (nämlich den eingeleiteten) steht das finite Verb in der rechten [Satzklammer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldermodell_des_deutschen_Satzes), wobei das [Nachfeld](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldermodell_des_deutschen_Satzes#Das_Nachfeld) in der Regel unbesetzt bleibt. Deshalb nennt man diese Sätze oft auch *Verbletztsätze*.

Das muss aber nicht so sein: Wie in Verberst- und Verbzweitsätzen können einzelne Satzglieder **ausgeklammert** und ins Nachfeld verschoben (man sagt auch rechtsversetzt) werden.

Spontan würden mir drei *Üblichkeitsgrade* einfallen (im den folgenden Beispielen ist jeweils die Satzklammer fett, das Nachfeld kursiv):

#### 1. Üblich

Konjunktional- und Infinitivphrasen mit *zu* sowie Relativsätze stehen sowohl in Verberst- als auch Verbzweit- und Verb'letzt'sätzen **oft** im Nachfeld:

> - Sie hat gewettet, **dass** sie schneller **laufen könne** *als er*. (vgl. die bereits oben [verlinkte Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39365))
>
>   Auch in V<sub>1</sub>- und V<sub>2</sub>-Sätzen:
>
>   - Sie **ist** schneller **gelaufen** *als er*.
>   - **Ist** sie schneller **gelaufen** *als er*?
> - Er war überrascht, **als** sie **wettete**, *schneller als er laufen zu können*.
> - Wir haben gesehen, **dass** sie die Wette **gewonnen hat**, *die sie mit ihm zuvor geschlossen hatte* (statt *… dass sie die Wette, die sie … hatte, gewonnen hat*).

#### 2. Weniger üblich, unüblich und manchmal gesteltzt

Dazu gehören meines Erachtens zum Beispiel Präpositionalphrasen und adverbiale Bestimmungen, welche anscheinend seltener im Nachfeld stehen:

> - Er behauptet, **dass** er sich **auskenne** *in der Stadt*.
> - Sie kamen wieder, **weil** es ihnen so gut **gefallen hatte** *letztes Mal*.
> - Der Vermieter bestand darauf, **dass** die Regeln einzuhalten **seien** *in einem ordentlichen Haus wie dem seinen*.

#### 3. Ungrammatisch

Bei Dativ- und Akkusativobjekten wirkt die Ausklammerung ungrammatisch (offenbar unabhängig von der Besetzung des Mittelfelds):

> - *Es war heiß, **obwohl** ich (heute Morgen) <s>**aufgemacht hatte** *das Fenster*</s>.
> - *Das erinnert mich an das Geschenk, **das** ich <s>zum Geburtstag **gemacht habe** *ihm*</s>.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Antwort! Sie ist sehr hilfreich